# Is there any git plumbing faster than git diff-files?

Tags: performance, git

I'm not sure if there is such a thing, but

```
$ time git diff-files --quiet
real    0m0.495s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

and although I assume it's blazingly fast (SHA-1 hashing all the 3680 tracked files on disk?), it would be nice with something even faster. Do you know of a faster way?

**Edit:** My i7 at work is ~3.7 times faster than my i5 at home. Is that to be expected? Is the instruction set on i7 packed with instructions that makes it SHA-1 like the wind?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shed some light on this task background

Comment: No, but it would be interesting, wouldn't it? I'm using it to generate a nice bash prompt. Like [so](http://lazybones-git.blogspot.se/2011/04/gitifying-da-prompt.html).

Comment: `git diff-files` is not calculating the hash of every file on your disk. It is comparing the `stat()` info (timestamp, especially) against the timestamp already stored in the index. Only if those differ will it consider checking the hash. Unless you have `core.ignoreStat` enabled, anyway...

Comment: @twalberg: put that in (answer) writing, and I'll accept it; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git diff-files` does not calculate the hash of every file in your working copy by default. The index contains copies of the timestamps and some other metadata from the last time the file was `git add`ed (or `git update-index` or several other operations that involve placing a record of the file in the index). `git diff-files`, as a first step, compares the metadata of the current file with the copy in the index, and if they are the same, it assumes the file has not been changed and does not compute a hash. If the metadata is different, then it performs a more expensive operation to see if the files are actually different - computing the hash. The full picture is actually more complicated than that, in light of things like the `assume-unchanged` attribute and so on, but that's the normal flow overview. There is also a configuration option `core.ignoreStat` that can be set - which is primarily targeted toward file systems where `stat()` is unreliable/inaccurate - to force `git` to skip that first step and only do hash comparisons, with the obvious impact on speed.

Answer (score 1):

If there was a faster way do do this, it would already be in `git diff-files`... and I *very* much doubt it is SHA-256-ing your files, that would take longer (you could time something like `cat $(git ls-files) | sha256` to get an idea how much time it takes to do so).